# UNION ALL for an undefined amount of tables

Tags: mysql

I have a multiple amount of tables starting with `art-` such as `art_1`, `art_485` ect ...
In these tables they are two colums that interest me: `date_added` and `path`.
I then want to take all tables starting with `art_` and compare the `date_added` to get the `path` of the latest `date_added`.
So i have got this code wich works for comparing two tables:

```
"SELECT `path`  
 FROM (SELECT `date_added`, `path` FROM `art_1` UNION ALL
  SELECT `date_added`, `path` FROM `art_5484`
 ) a
ORDER BY date_added DESC
LIMIT 1;"
```

This works fine for comparing two given tables; but now; how do a UNION ALL for all existing tables starting with `art_` ??? (the numbers after `art_` are kind of random)

All existing tables starting with `art_` would be :

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'art\_%'
```

How do i go about this problem ?? if somebody could help me that would be great !

Comment: You should fix your data structure so you store all the "art" information in a single table.  Multiple parallel tables are usually a sign of poor database design.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The problem about that is that the table "art" would be huge because in each `art_...` table  each row corresponds to different images with other 8 colums for info on that image. And with over 15 rows on each `art_...`, if i concatenate all these tables; it just wouldn't practical i don't think.

Comment: 15 rows?  Are you joking?  MySQL can handle tables with billions of rows.

Comment: So you suggest that i put all the info in one big table ?? Will it not slow down requests ? Sorry if i am asking questions that seem stupid; but i am discovering.

Comment: Without seeing your table structure and some data it's hard to estimate the load, but it is very, very likely that MySQL will have no trouble having all your data in a single table.

Comment: "if i concatenate all these tables; it just wouldn't practical i don't think." you mean if you stored a lot of data in one table and later performed queries to show subsets of that data... yeah, that's exactly what a database is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having so many separate tables seems like a bit of a bad database design, but I'll assume that there's a good reason for it and they can't be combined into a single table!

You can create a stored procedure in MySQL that defines a cursor to iterate/loop through each table in the database (that starts with 'art-') and adds the relevant information into a temporary table.

### Example:

This isn't tested, so see how it goes. This code creates a stored procedure called `getArtData`, so all you need to do *after running this code* is to call the stored procedure.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS getArtData $$

CREATE PROCEDURE getArtData(recordOffset INT, recordCount INT)

BEGIN
        DECLARE tableName VARCHAR(255);
        DECLARE endOfTables INT DEFAULT 0;

        DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
            SELECT t.table_name
            FROM information_schema.tables t
            WHERE t.table_schema = DATABASE()
              AND t.table_type='BASE TABLE'
              AND t.table_name LIKE 'art\_%';
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET endOfTables = 1;

        DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp;

        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (
            `date_added` DATE NOT NULL,
            `path` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL) ENGINE=MEMORY;

        OPEN cur;

        tablesLoop: LOOP
            FETCH cur INTO tableName;

            IF endOfTables = 1 THEN
                LEAVE tablesLoop;
            END IF;

            SET @s = CONCAT('INSERT INTO tmp (date_added, path) SELECT `date_added`, `path` FROM ', tableName, ' ORDER BY date_added DESC');
            PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
            EXECUTE stmt;

        END LOOP;

        CLOSE cur;

        SELECT `date_added`, `path` FROM tmp ORDER BY `date_added` DESC LIMIT recordOffset, recordCount;

    END $$

DELIMITER ;


-- Using the stored procedure
-- Get the most-recent record
CALL getArtData(0,1);

-- Get the 2nd most-recent record
CALL getArtData(1,1);

-- Get the 10 most-recent records
CALL getArtData(0,10);
```

Comment: Okey thanks; i will look into how to create stored procedures in mysql then.

Comment: I've updated the answer to have some example code you can try out. It creates the stored procedure - all you should have to do is execute/call it.

Comment: Wow thanks for taking the time to giving me such an complete answer. I copy/pasted the code but they seems to be syntax error at the moment, as i am nwe to  mysql procedure code; i will learn more about it to try and find why it isn't working

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
            SELECT t.table_name
            FROM inform' at line 13

Comment: @Jackymamouth I just set up a testing database and fixed the stored procedure to work with it. Please use the updated code.

Comment: @underscore_d It's more of a "benefit of the doubt" deal.  ;)

Comment: Ahhh dude you are a LEGEND !! Your procedure works great, but they is a little problem; it gives back the lastest `path` for each `art_` table; So if I have 3 tables starting with `art_` it will give back 3 lines with the latest path of each table: So then i just :
`SELECT `path`  
FROM (CALL `getArtData`();) a
ORDER BY date_added DESC
LIMIT 1 ;`
They is a syntax error; you can't implement a procedure in a FROM like that?

Comment: Are you only wanting to know the 1 most-recent artwork across all tables?

Comment: BTW, no, you can't use the syntax `SELECT field FROM (CALL storedProcedure()) ORDER BY field` in MySQL. You want to change the `SELECT` statement at the end of the stored procedure to alter the output of the stored procedure.

Comment: Yes; sorry if I wasn't clear about that ...
And they is also a problem if i want the second most-recent artwork...
Because if i had just two tables i would  add `OFFSET $n ` with n=1 if i wanted the second most recent for example . ( no worries if you don't have a quick fix for this, you have already help a lot )

Comment: @Jackymamouth I've just given an updated version of the stored procedure that you pass the offset and count to, e.g. `getArtData(0,1)` or `getArtData(1,1)` would give you the 1st most recent and 2nd most recent records respectively. Try it out.  :)  That's the "proper" way of using stored procedures in this case instead of using the `SELECT` approach.  :)

Comment: Great! Hopefully it's been a good introduction into stored procedures with MySQL - they're very powerful, so are good to learn. It's still worth fixing up your table design though to make things easier in the future.  ;)  Good luck!  :)